# Calling member function from another class C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I want my `Class B` to be able to call a member function from `Class A`. What is the best way to approach this?

For some context, here are snippets of an abbreviated version of my code:

```
    class Time{
        public:
        Time();
        Time(int hour, int minute);
        int time_GetHour() const;
        -----
        private:
        int hour;
        int minute;
    };

    int Time::time_GetHour() const{
        return hour;
    }


    class DaTime{
        public:
        DaTime();
        DaTime(Day day, Time start, Time end);
        dt_Difference(DaTime &a, DaTime &b) const;

        private:
        int duration;
        Time start;
        Time end;
    };

    int DaTime::dt_Difference(DaTime &a, DaTime &b) const{
        int diff_hour = 0;
        int diff_min = 0;
        int diff = 0;

        if(dt_LessThanOrEqual(a,b)){
            diff_hour = (b.time_GetHour() - a.time_GetHour())*60;
            diff_min = b.time_GetHour() - a.time_GetHour();
            diff = diff_hour + diff_min;
            return diff;
        }
    }
```

The error I am getting is stating that my class `DaTime` has no member `time_GetHour()`, which I can see that. I am asking what is the best way to approach a fix or to bypass this error? Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what `DaTime` is supposed to be extend functionality or use `Time` internally. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21692193/1387612) for answer.

Comment: What do you want time_GetHour to do? And why are you putting `stuff_` before your method names?

Comment: I want `time_GetHour` to just just return an already existing `hour` from an instantiation of the class `Time`.

Comment: Also, I should point out that I want `DaTime` to use `Time` internally, and not extend the functionality. At least I think so. That's why I haven't made `DaTime` inherit from `Time`, I thought that wouldn't be the best approach.

Comment: One thing you could do is class inheritance, another thing you could do is make a time instance a member of DaTime ( remember class instances can be treated almost like variables). That's not to say that is all you can do though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you clarified you want to use the `Time` class internally instead of inheriting it, you could simply fix your problems by accessing the member variables you mentioned:

```
diff_hour = (b.end.time_GetHour() - a.start.time_GetHour())*60;
```

However I'm not sure to match your necessary time math with the sample above.

BTW, the two operand operation samples you have should be either static class functions, or even global operator definitions IMHO.

Comment: Ah, yes. Me capitalizing `class` was just a mistake copying it over to here. Thank you for your help and I will give that a shot.

Comment: @AllenS see my updates ...

Comment: Thanks. That worked! If I understand this correctly, that was because I was trying to access the function directly without giving the correct member variable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a function in `Time` to return the minutes. Here's a revised `Time`.

```
class Time
{
   public:
      Time();
      Time(int hour, int minute);
      int time_GetHour() const;
      int time_GetMinute() const;
   private:
      int hour;
      int minute;
};

int Time::time_GetHour() const
{
   return hour;
}

int Time::time_GetMinute() const
{
   return minute;
}
```

Your definition of `DaTime` is a little bit unclear. Do you need to store `start` and `end` as well as `duration`? Can you get away with storing either `start` and `end` or `duration`? What purpose does the input `Day day` serve in construction of `DaTime`?

If you have already computed `duration`, `DaTime::dt_Difference` can be altered a little bit to use `duration` instead of relying on the member functions of `Time`.

```
int DaTime::dt_Difference(DaTime &a, DaTime &b) const
{
   int diff = 0;

   if(dt_LessThanOrEqual(a,b))
   {
       diff = b.duration - a.duration;
   }
   return diff;
}
```

However, the way you have decalred`DaTime::dt_Difference`, it will be awkward to use. You have to have lines like:

```
DaTime dt1;
DaTime dt2;
DaTime dt3;
int difference = dt1.dt_Difference(dt2, dt3);
```

Notice that the state of `dt1` has no impact on the return value of `dt_Difference`. Is this how intended to use it? A better alternative would be to change the declaration of `dt_Difference` to be:

```
int dt_Difference(const DaTime &a) const;
```

Then, the implementation would be altered to be:

```
int DaTime::dt_Difference(const DaTime &a) const
{
   int diff = 0;

   if(dt_LessThanOrEqual(*this,a))
   {
       diff = b.duration - this->duration;
   }
   return diff;
}
```

Then, your usage could be changed to:

```
DaTime dt1;
DaTime dt2;
int difference = dt1.dt_Difference(dt2);
```

In addition, there is no need to have names `time_GetHour` and `time_GetMinute`. `time` is redundant since you are dealing with the class `Time`. You could change them to `getHour` and `getSecond`. Similarly, you could also change `dt_Difference` to `operator-`. You could also replace the use of `if(dt_LessThanOrEqual(*this, a))` by `if ( *this <= a )`. The second form is more readable than the first form.

In summary, your code could be changed to look like the following:

```
class Time
{
   public:
      Time();
      Time(int hour, int minute);
      int getHour() const;
      int getMinute() const;
   private:
      int hour;
      int minute;
};

int Time::getHour() const
{
   return hour;
}

int Time::getMinute() const
{
   return minute;
}

class DaTime
{
   public:
      DaTime();
      DaTime(Day day, Time start, Time end);
      int operator-(const DaTime &a) const;
      bool operator<=(const DaTime& rhs) const;

   private:
      int duration;
};

int DaTime::operator-(const DaTime &a) const
{
   int diff = 0;

   if( a <= *this )
   {
       diff = this->duration - a.duration;
   }
   return diff;
}

DaTime dt1;
DaTime dt2;
int difference = dt2 - dt1;
```

Comment: TL;DR; That kind of detail doesn't seem to be necessary to answer the OP's (primary) question here ...